# Upload Plugin Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm new in CakePHP and trying to learn but I don't understand this part very well..

I'm using this CakePHP [Upload](https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload) plugin to upload images for users(avatars) and using imagick it resize image to certain sizes(thumbs)...

I follow Upload plugin instructions for uploading image. I manage to store image file and image directory in database. So column photo in database would be `(imagename.jpg)` and photo directory would be userid,

for example (35). Image also appear in `files/user/userid/imagename.jpg`

Now may be it's funny but how I output this image and display in view file ? Also is there possibility to randomize file name ? (so the file name is not same as uploaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to view your upload in view files of CakePHP

you write in ctp files like

```
$html->link($html->image('files/user/".$userId."/".$ImageName."', array('alt'=>"User Image", 'border'=>"0"))
,'#',array('id'=>$userId, 'escape'=>false));
```

let me know if i can help you further,

Comment: @liyakat.how can we upload files via ajax using this plugin?